# Does the Xcode 6.3 Beta support an iOS Simulator of iOS 7

Tags: xcode

I've updated Xcode and updated my Swift project, but it's only letting me test in iOS 8.3. Do the betas only let you test the upcoming iOS Beta?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Download the iOS 7 simulator in the settings.

[image]

Comment: I did that, but when I select "Manage Devices" in the Simulator, it only lets me select 8.3